# Xamarin.Forms Custom Render with Xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/faultcodes_hex">

    <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

    <padding
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp"/>

    <corners android:radius="3dp"/>

</shape>
```

this should change the list entries as in the picture 1 (white entries), currently the entries are arranged normally.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q79R.png)

XAML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="xDeleteApp.Views.ItemsPage" Title="xDelete"
             x:Name="BrowseItemsPage" BackgroundColor="#1F91F1">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Add" Clicked="ConnectCar_Clicked">
            <ToolbarItem.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="UWP" Value="add.png" />
                    <On Platform="Android" Value="@drawable/connected" />
                </OnPlatform>
            </ToolbarItem.Icon>
        </ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Meine Autos" FontSize="20" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#1F91F1"/>
        <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="true" RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected" BackgroundColor="#1F91F1">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="10">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Text}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" FontSize="16" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}" FontSize="13" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

It is saved in the Android drawable folder.
How and where do I have to call the XML that it will be used?
Or am I generally on the wrong track? Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**

Actual the list entries looks like this (picture 2), but I want that it looks like in the picture above (picture 1).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3JHQ.png)

Comment: What exactly are you looking to accomplish with the custom renderer?

Comment: The main idea about xamarin forms is not having to use os-dependant ui definitions. You seem to be undertaking a big effort just to revert that.

Of course, i could have mistaken your question. Could you please state what you are trying to do there and what is your intention behind it?